# $ \frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{p-1} =\frac{a}{b}$ implies $p^2 \mid a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $$ \frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{p-1} =\frac{a}{b}$$ with $(a,b)=1$
>   and $p$ a prime number, (
>   $p>3$ ). Show that $ p^2 |a $.

I can't solve it.

Comment: This is Wolstenholme's theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem

Comment: If it has the name of someone, its proof is not trivial at all.